# How to fetch a bit in IA32 assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86, bit

How can I check if a bit in some position of a word is 1 with the IA32 assembly language?

Answer (score 4):

`Test`, something like:

```
value = 000100h

mov eax, your_word
test eax, value
jnz was_set
```

Comment: I think your branch logic is inverted - `s/jnz wasnt_set/jz wasnt_set/` or `s/jnz wasnt_set/jnz was_set/` perhaps ?

Comment: A word is 16bit so you would have to use `ax` instead of `eax` which is a double word.

Comment: @DipSwitch: it depends on whose definition of "word" you go by. On most mainframes (for one example) `word` has meant 32 bits since long before these x86 things were even dreamt of yet... :-) But yes, by Intel't terminology, you need to either use ax or movzx (or possibly movsx, but probably not if you're doing bit manipulation).

Comment: Hmm I see at wikipedia, didn't know... I learned at school that a word is 16bits... :)

Comment: @DipSwitch: mostly `word` means whatever the native size of the registers are. In Intel's case, however, they started out using `word` when the native size was 16 bits, and they've stuck to that even though the registers have grown to 32 and now 64 bits (finally surpassing the 60 bits that was a "word" when I first wrote assembly language *way* too long ago to think about).

Comment: I see, and may I ask why you use test and not `bt` and `adc` or `jc`/`jnc`?

Comment: @DipSwitch: Mostly because I wrote more assembly code for processors before the 386 (which was when `bt` got added). Truth to tell, however, I've never seen much good reason to use work at using `bt` instead. Strangely, since it was added to the instruction set later, the encoding for `bt` is often actually larger than for `test`.

Comment: What if I do orl 00100, my_word for testing the 3th bit? Keeping to shift in this way i can check all the bit in my word. Is that correct?

Comment: @Aegidius: `orl` doesn't do anything useful in this context - it just sets the bit - perhaps you mean `andl` ?

Comment: @Aegidius: As @Paul R said, `or` isn't useful in this context. `and` is, but it modifies the destination operand -- `test` is essentially the same as `and`, except that it only modifies the flag bits, not the operands.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to say andl. It modify the dst register, but I have a copy in the stack, so it's not a problem.

Comment: @Aegidius: `test` indicates explicitly that you don't care about the return value, just the condition codes. Also, it may be faster, since it eliminates potential dependencies on the result. BTW, you should always think of `test` as an `and` discarding the result, and `cmp` as a `sub` discarding the result.

Answer (score 2):

NASM:

```
bt ax, <POS> ; test if bit at position is set: 1 means carry will be set 0 means carry will be unset
adc eax, 0   ; add 0 + carry to eax
```

You could also use `jc` (jump carry set) `jnc` (jump carry not set)